# Whats the schema to store hashed passwords in mysql using sqlalchemy ORM?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My current schema is this, I want to store password in bytes.

```
class User(db.Model):
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40))
    last_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40))
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120))
    account_created: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    account_updated: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(
        default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: The size of the fields indicate that you are planning to store the password in plain text. You don't do that. Hash the password with an appropriate function.

Comment: Yes you should hash the passwords with an appropriate library like Fernet then you could just convert it to a string that would then be stored in your db. You could store your key as well as string in the db so as to easily decrypt the password. If you need an example let me know.